# Serving Static site with Caddy gives connection refused

Tags: centos, caddy, caddyfile

I have caddy installed and running in my CentOS server,mainly I have it to proxy request to 2 Golang applications that I have running and it's working great! Now, I need to serve a static site, but i't returning `connection refused`

The structure of my directory is:

```
|--Caddyfile
|--mygolang1
|--mygolang2
|--FolderofMyStaticSite
|-----MySite
|-------Public
|----------index.html
```

And the caddyfile configuration is

```
:9000 {
   root FolderofMyStaticSite/MySite/
   log  mySite
}

subdomain1.domain.com {
  gzip
  proxy / :7000 {
     except /assets /robots.txt
  }
}

subdomain2.domain.com {
  proxy / :8000 {
    max_fails 1
  }
}
```

Then when I go to the browser and open `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000` I get connection refused, why port 9000? it's because I have it only for testing not for production but I need a port to hear that site. What Am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have TLS configured correctly, your Caddyfile looks good. Are you sure you have Caddy running and port 9000 open?

Comment: @JeremiahMegel yes TLS was configured fine, caddy is running because the other applications are available trought the browser. I checked the list of ports and port 9000 is not used by any other process

Comment: What version of Caddy are you running? (`caddy -version`)